# Provide access to a third party app using Azure AD

Tags: amazon-ec2, azure-active-directory, amazon-cognito

I've installed a third party app on an AWS EC2 instance. The requirement is when user clicks the web url of this application, user should be authenticated using organization's Azure AD. Since it's a third party app I can not integrate Azure AD with it in the code. Any suggestions on how it can be achieved are welcome. I'm trying out AWS cognito service but so far it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

**Please check if you have followed the steps below  and if anything was missed.**

Version of Azure AD- free won’t support the onboarding of enterprise apps. So we need to upgrade Azure AD.

1. Go to enterprise application>new application>non-gallery
   application>activate for enterprise account (which is minimum
   requirement ,can select premium also)>give AWS app name.

[image]

2. Go to single sign-on by opening the application in azure >choose the
   SAML option >Download federation metadata XML as shown below.
3. Then go to AWS management console>>Enable AWS SSO(Only certain
   regions are available to enable SSO,please check that).
4. Choose the identity source

[image]

[image]

5. Change the identity provider>>select external identity
   provider>download AWS SSO SAML metadata file which can be used later
   in azure side.
6. In IdP SAML metadata>insert the azure federation metadata file which
   is downloaded previously from azure and then review and confirm .

[image]

7. Now go to azure portal where you previously previously created aws app name>Go to single sign on >Upload metadata file>select the file which we previously downloaded from the aws portal>click on add>then click save on basic SAML configuration.

[image]

[image]

[image]

- Say yes to test sso if pop up for testing appears.

Now we can provide automatic provisioning.When new user is created in azure AD ,then it must flow in AWS SSO .We can make few users a part of AD group in order to try signin from users.

8. Now go to AWS Portal and click on >Enable automatic provisioning.Copy
   SCIM Endpoint and access token .Go to azure side in the app

   > provisioning>>Select automatic in provisioning mode>>Then paste the the SCIM end point in  Tenant URL and accesstoken>click on Test connection and save the configuration.

[image]

- Then go for mappings >select Synchronize AAD users to custom app
  sso>leave default settings>You can select required attributes
  -select beside externalID mailnickname and change the Source attribute to ObjectId(choosing the unique ID on AD side to flow in
  AWS)>Also edit mail>change source attribute to userprincipalname.

> I.    Ensure the user only has one value for phoneNumber/email
>
> II.   Remove the duplicate attributes. For example, having two different
> attributes being mapped from Azure AD both mapped to
> "phoneNumber_____" would result in the error if both attributes in
> Azure AD have values. Only having one attribute mapped to a
> "phoneNumber____ " attribute would resolve the error.

[image]

- Now go ahead and map users and groups
- Search for groups in portal and add groups >Security type>give a
  group name  ,description and membership type as assigned>click on create.
- Create two or more groups in the same way if needed ,After that
  these groups are to be filled with particular users for particular
  group .
  Now create few users .For that Search for users in portal>new user>give name >add the user to one of the created groups and assign .
  [image]
- After creating users and groups , go to users and groups in your
  enterprise app(recommended to select groups rather than individual
  and then delete unwanted users)
- Go back to provisioning and make the provision status as ON.
  Now do the mapping of AD group to access certain AWS accounts by
  giving permission sets.
- Go to permission sets and select the group or users . You can give
  existing job functional access or you can create custom policies .

[image]

[image]

[image]

- Now go to settings in AWS portal copy the url and open the page of
  the url which redirects to the signin. Give the user credentials and
  access is possibleas per the given permissions.
  [image]